# then() syntax in Dart for non argument methods

Tags: dart, methods, conditional-statements, future

I have two methods to execute. I want to execute **method1()** then **method2()**. These two methods don't have any arguments only some conditions then what will be the syntax of my code?

```
Future method1() {
  //Something;
}

Future method2() {
  //Somthing;
}

method() {
  //Execute [Method1] then [Method2]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either mark `method` as `async` to do:

```
Future method() async {
  await method1();
  return method2(); // or await method2();
}
```

Or use `then()` like this:

```
Future method() => method1().then((_) => method2());
```